# How to display all the icons in FontAwesome library in a ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, font-awesome

I want to show all the icons in the [FontAwesome](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) library in a ListView.

Is there any way I can get all the icons available in the library as a list?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is better way but in the example directory of the package they have a list of all icons : [List of all icons as Dart array](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/blob/master/example/lib/icons.dart)

Answer (score -2):

You can find a complete list of icons on the Font Awesome website:
https://fontawesome.com/icons

Go to View All 26,107 icons button at the bottom of the screen and a list of all icons will appear to you.
[image: list of all icons]